# Alternative Asp.NET Core Authentication Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have searched here as well as google, but couldn't find a clear answer. I am curious if there are any good alternative frameworks for handling authentication/authorization in the manner that Identity does for ASP.NET core.

The standard Identity Framework seems good except that I don't want to use Entity Framework and also would want to move this framework outside of my MVC project, but it seems that to accomplish this inside of Identity would be a large task.

For example, how does StackOverflow handle their authentication, (or any other large enterprise site)?

Comment: u can look into aws cognito, okta etc. if that suits your needs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use default Identity, Microsoft has provided many ways to custom this. You can read in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for using Cookie Authentication without Identity or [Custom Policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

So many Nuget libraries can help you to integrate with SaaS Authentication such as Auth0, AWS Cognito, etc.